# Issue with Sticky Menu in Chrome which is not sticking to the top as it works on other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Its an issue which in happening the website

[www.nysafoundation.org](http://www.nysafoundation.org)

and **happening only on chrome and only for the home page** (index.php)

Other pages (team/donate etc..)  are working fine in all the browsers and even in chrome as well. 
Homepage is working fine in other browsers like Firefox etc

Its kind of wired. I tried a lot to identify it. If I remove the page sections its working fine in chrome.

So i feel **its something to do with CSS part of those page sections.**

[image]

*It may not the opt place to ask but I dont have any other option.* 
**HTML**

```
    <div id="navigation-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 95px;"><nav id="navigation" class="is-sticky">
<div class="container">
<nav style="display: block;"><ul id="menu" class="shadow"><li><a href="/activities">Activities</a></li>
<li><a href="/volunteer">Volunteer</a></li>
<li><a href="/reports">Reports</a></li>
<li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#blog">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/team">Team</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a data-target="#" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Donation &nbsp; <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/donation">Donate Now</a> </li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/donation/#exemption">Tax Benefit</a> </li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/notify">Notify</a> </li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/receipt">Download Receipt</a> </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</nav></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sticky-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-bottom: -95px !important;
}

.sticky-wrapper #navigation {
padding: 30px 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
}




.sticky-wrapper.is-sticky #navigation,.is-sticky #navigation .dropdown-menu {
padding: 15px 0;
border-bottom: solid 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? You need to be clearer in your question..

Comment: @celt sticky menu is not working properly in chrome. please check the screen capture attached

Comment: Please include the code on the question don't ask for inspect some website that later is fixed an then the question is useless for future users

Comment: @sedhuait 'It is not working properly' is not very helpful when we don't know how you want it to work.

Comment: @Andy: Sorry will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your question is but I believe it is that your menu does not stick to the top of the page all the time. I have played around with the web inspector on chrome and I found that by removing position:relative from your .sticky-wrapper class the menu stayed on the top. Your old sticky-wrapper class looked like this:

```
.sticky-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-bottom: -95px !important;
}
```

This is what your new sticky-wrapper class should look like to solve this problem:

```
.sticky-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-bottom: -95px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. If possible can u explain how it was working in other browsers / even other pages in chrome were working ??

Comment: Some browsers handle the CSS differently so it could just be a specific issue with Chrome.